# Timestamp in two columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-timestamp

As a teacher, I am trying to create a Google sheet for the students to use as they sign in and out of class. I have successfully used code to auto insert a time stamp into column A if Column C is edited. However, I can't get a new time to be inserted into column B after after column E has been edited.

The code I am using is below. Can you please help me?

```
/*Updated and maintain by internetgeeks.org*/ 

function onEdit(event) 
{ 
 var timezone = "GMT-5"; 
 var timestamp_format = "MMMM-dd HH:mm"; // Timestamp Format. 

 var updateColName = "Student First, Last Name"; 
 var timeStampColName = "Sign Out"; 

 var sheet = event.source.getSheetByName('Feb 16'); //Name of the sheet where   you want to run this script.

 var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange(); 
 var editColumn = actRng.getColumn(); 
 var index = actRng.getRowIndex(); 
 var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues(); 

 var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(timeStampColName); 
 var updateCol = headers[0].indexOf(updateColName); updateCol = updateCol+1; 

 if (dateCol > -1 && index > 1 && editColumn == updateCol);  {
        var cell = sheet.getRange(index, dateCol + 1); 
        var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format); cell.setValue(date); }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I modified the script so that it accepts arrays of column headers:

- updateColNames lists the columns that you want to keep track of
- timeStampColNames lists the columns where timestamps should appear, in the same order.

There is now a `for` loop that goes over the tracked columns one by one, comparing them to the edit location, and inserting timestamp when needed.

I also changed the handling of sheet name, because the original version appeared to edit the sheet named Feb 16 regardless of where the edit was.

```
function onEdit(e) { 
  var timezone = "GMT-5"; 
  var timestamp_format = "MMMM-dd HH:mm"; // Timestamp Format. 

  var updateColNames = ["Student First, Last Name", "Another Column to Watch"]; 
  var timeStampColNames = ["Name Timestamp", "Another Timestamp"]; 

  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() == 'Feb 16') {    // Name of the sheet to track

    var editColumn = e.range.getColumn(); 
    var row = e.range.getRow(); 
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues(); 

    if (row > 1) {
      for (var i = 0; i < updateColNames.length; i++) {
        var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(timeStampColNames[i]); 
        var updateCol = headers[0].indexOf(updateColNames[i]) + 1;  
        if (dateCol > -1 && editColumn == updateCol) {
          var cell = sheet.getRange(row, dateCol + 1); 
          var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format); 
          cell.setValue(date); 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```